# My joomla installation doesn't display IEframe or script

Tags: javascript, joomla

It's bothering me for a couple of days.

### The problem is with my joomla installation I think.

Here's my goal:

I want to display IEframe or text/javascript so I go through module > new > Custom HTML.

I access the default joomla editor and insert the source code `<>` and set the module position and name.

---

Here's my problem:

On the side site, I can view only the name of the module, the content is missing.

On the other hand the view-source:

```html
<div class=" col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
  <div class="t3-module module " id="Mod103"><div class="module-inner">
     <h3 class="module-title ">
       <span>YllixMedia</span>
    </h3>
      <div class="module-ct">
        <div class="custom"  >
          <form>
            <p>
               <script src="http://yllix.com/banner.php?section=General&amp;pub=934318&amp;format=300x250&amp;ga=g" type="text/javascript">                        </script>
               <script src="http://yllix.com/layer.php?section=General&amp;pub=934318&amp;ga=g&amp;show=1&amp;fp" type="text/javascript"></script>
               </p>
           </form>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that you can try to resolve this problem on your site.

1. Set up text filtering options for using JavaScript safely inside HTML source editor.

   - Open Content → Article Manager → Options → Text Filters → Set **No Filtering** for user groups → Save.
2. Allow  Tag from Text Editor plugin settings.

   - Go to Extensions → Plug-in Manager → Find Enabled Text Editor(TinyMCE) → Advanced Options → Prohibited Elements → Remove `<Script>` tag → Save.
3. Use the 'HTML' mode when pasting the JavaScript codes into HTML.

Comment: it's working on internet explorer and firefox but is not working on google chrome